# How can I set Vim to obey accents of my spoken language?

Tags: windows, vim, gvim, localization

When pressing `w` or `e` in sentences with accents (written in my native language), such as the first one (marked `**`) here:

```
**Éj-mélyből fölzengő**
- csing-ling-ling - száncsengő.
Száncsengő - csing-ling-ling -
tél csendjén halkan ring.          [1]
```

the characters `ő`, `ö`, among others [2], make my gVim think they are word-ends so it stops on them (in Normal mode). gVim stops on the positions marked with `_` where it shouldn't:

`Éj-mélyb_ől f_ölzeng_ő`.

I would like to set gVim so it properly handle words even when containing accents and other local characters. But where do I set this?

I use it on **Win32**, vim v 7.3.46.

---

appendix **credit & version & info**

[[1](http://web.archive.org/web/20120411104825/http://marci.co-net.hu/versek.htm#We%C3%B6res%20S%C3%A1ndor:%20Sz%C3%A1ncseng%C5%91)] - [excerpt of a poem by Weöres Sándor](http://web.archive.org/web/20120411104825/http://marci.co-net.hu/versek.htm#We%C3%B6res%20S%C3%A1ndor:%20Sz%C3%A1ncseng%C5%91)

[2] - "others", not mentioned here :) like `í`, `ű` are also a problem. On the other hand, gVim seems to already *work* with `é` and `á`.

---

**gVim version info:**

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 27 2010 17:59:02)
Included patches: 1-46
Compiled by Bram@KIBAALE
Big version with GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
+conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff
+digraphs -dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi
+file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +gettext/dyn -hangul_input
+iconv/dyn +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak
+lispindent +listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse
+mouseshape +multi_byte_ime/dyn +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg +ole
-osfiletype +path_extra +perl/dyn +persistent_undo -postscript +printer
-profile +python/dyn +python3/dyn +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby/dyn
+scrollbind +signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop
+syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white +tcl/dyn -tgetent
-termresponse +textobjects +title +toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit
+virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu
+windows +writebackup -xfontset -xim -xterm_save +xpm_w32
```

Comment: What is the output of `:set encoding?`, `:set fileencoding?`, `:set fileencodings?`? I can do `bwe` just fine in your example with `:set encoding=utf-8`.

Comment: all encodings were `cp1250`, except `fileencodings` what is still `ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1`. I `set encoding=utf-8`, reloaded the file (the encoding change first got it messed up) and now it works. Thanks! :) I'm newbee. :) Would you like to add it as answer so I could accept it?

Comment: by the way, what happens here? (when vim "goes wrong" with those accented chars in cp1250?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the output of these commands?

```
:set encoding?
:set fileencoding?
:set fileencodings?
```

I can do `bwe` just fine in your example with `:set encoding=utf-8`.

Ideally, you could add `set encoding=utf-8` to your `_VIMRC`.

Comment: encodings were `cp1250`, except fileencodings what was (still is) `ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1`. Then `set encoding=utf-8` solved the problem, thanks! :) ps. Don't forget to reload the file / vim. ;)